# Google script html service with Zxing bar code scanner

Tags: android, html, zxing

I have the following script running through Google Script HTML service. The plan is to use it on our Android phones to call the Zxing QR scanner and then return the value from the scan. I would then have script to put the QR into a Google spreadsheet. This Script throws an error when run through Google Apps script HTML on an Android device. Thanks for your help!

```
<html>

<body style="margin:0px;font-family:tahoma" onhashchange="getHash()">
<input id=barcode type=text >
<input style="width:100px;height:100px" type=button value="Scan" onclick="getScan()">
<p id="message"></p>

<script type="text/javascript" >

function getScan(){
    var href=window.location.href;//works
    var ptr=href.lastIndexOf("#");
    if(ptr>0){
        href=href.substr(0,ptr);
    }
      window.location.href="zxing://scan/?ret="+escape(href+"#{CODE}");

}
var changingHash=false;
function getHash(){
    if(!changingHash){
        changingHash=true;
        var hash=window.location.hash.substr(1);
        document.getElementById('barcode').value=unescape(hash);
        window.location.hash="";   
        changingHash=false;
      }else{
        message.innerHTML = "Input " +  document.getElementById('barcode').value;
        //Do something with barcode here
      }
}
</script>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: "This Script throws an error when run through Google Apps script HTML on an Android device" -- you may wish to explain what the error is.

Comment: All I get is a fault image. I'm using Chrome on Android device. Similar to the  following link except it is just the image with nothing else. Im brand new to HTML, I tryied using a try block and the error said I accessed the Zxing. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202641/is-chromes-this-webpage-is-not-found-correct

Comment: This is where I get the code from:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/zxing/dQ4_wKjut1M/vOaguJIss3wJ